# Show fields that match the condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a table where I want to show ALL the "Projects" where all it's items have "STATUS" = 'A'.

This is an example of the main table:

```
+--------------+-----------+-------+
| PROJECT      | COST_ITEM | STATUS|
+--------------+-----------+-------+
| S/180779/01  |    3925   |   A   |        
| S/180779/02  |    4000   |   P   |
+--------------+-----------+-------+
```

And I'm trying to work with this code :

```
select project,status
from C_PROJI_ADD_DOC 
where status = 'A'
GROUP BY project,status
```

Example of what I get:

```
+--------------+------+
| PROJECT      |STATUS|
+--------------+------+
| S/180063/02  |   A  |        
| S/180157/01  |   A  |
| S/180063/03  |   A  |
| S/180063/05  |   A  |
+--------------+------+
```

Down below it's an REAL example of what I get:

[image]

If I run this query, other projects appear, like 'S/180779/01', but when I open this project, some items have STATUS = 'P'

```
+--------------+-----------+-------+
| PROJECT      | COST_ITEM | STATUS|
+--------------+-----------+-------+
| S/180779/01  |    3925   |   A   |        
| S/180779/01  |    3927   |   A   |
| S/180779/01  |    3928   |   P   |        
| S/180779/01  |    3930   |   P   |
+--------------+-----------+-------+
```

[image]

How could I make it to show only the projects where all it's items are as STATUS = 'A'

Comment: We can't read your data in the image. Please use formatted text, cut down to the relevant columns.

Comment: @DaleK I'm not trying to find for an specific project, the query it's to find for all projects where all of the "Item_Code" STATUS = 'A'

Comment: Is that your **whole** query?

Comment: @DaleK I editted the question, hopefully it's more clear now what I'm trying to ask

Comment: And I note you continue to add these unviewable images... and have been asked not to before. Please don't do it anymore.

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah that's the whole query, I know it's a really basic stuff, but I just can't get it to work.+

Comment: @DaleK The "Items" are not needed, so that's why they are not on the query. I'm using GROUP BY to group the "PROJECT" and "STATUS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to filtering for projects that have 'A', you need a condition that no 'P' can exist for the same projects:

```
select distinct project, status
from   C_PROJI_ADD_DOC P1
where  status = 'A'
and    not exists (
    select 1
    from   C_PROJI_ADD_DOC P2
    where  P2.status = 'P'
    and    P2.project = P1.project
)
```

Comment: @dontknowcoding If you would have started with the `Project` table rather than the `Item` table it would have been obvious that's what you needed. And then you won't need the `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the *projects* -- as your question suggests -- then aggregation is a good option:

```
select project
from C_PROJI_ADD_DOC 
group by project
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'A';
```